# ITextRenderer repeats the same title in all pdf files

Tags: java, pdf, xhtml, pdf-generation, itext

If I use the same `ITextRenderer` to create two PDF files from two distinct XHTML files, the second PDF document will have the same title as the first one.

The xhtml files:

`file1.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Title 1</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
   Body 1 
 </body>
</html>
```

`file2.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Title 2</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
   Body 2 
 </body>
</html>
```

And the testing Java code that reuses a `ITextRenderer` instance:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class TitleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        renderer.setDocument("file:file1.xhtml");
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream("file1.pdf"));

        renderer.setDocument("file:file2.xhtml");
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream("file2.pdf"));
    }
}
```

The created `file2.pdf` will have "*Body 2*" as its content, but its title (the PDF meta-information) will be "*Title 1*".

Is it wrong to reuse an `ITextRenderer` instace to begin with? Or is it a iText bug? Is there some "clear" method for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** add this line

```
 renderer.getOutputDevice().setMetadata("title", null);
```

before reusing `renderer`. Like this:

```
    renderer.setDocument("file:file1.xhtml");
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream("file1.pdf"));

    renderer.getOutputDevice().setMetadata("title", null); // <-----

    renderer.setDocument("file:file2.xhtml");
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream("file2.pdf"));
```

**Explanation:** The `ITextRenderer` reuses its instance of `ITextOutputDevice`, which only uses the xhtml's title if no title has been set before in the pfd meta-data. This happens on [this line of the source code](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-pdf/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextOutputDevice.java#L1155).

It's still not clear if this is a bug or if reusing an `ITextRenderer` is wrong to begin with.